# AudioPlaybackCapture (Android 10) not working and recording empty sounds

Tags: java, android, recording, audiorecord

I tried to use new AudioPlaybackCapture method to record some media in an android 10 device. But unfortunately my code which uses this API does not seem to be working well.

Here I used an activity which starts a separate service for media recording. That service is registered to a broadcast receiver to start and stop recordings. And the broadcast intents are fired using my main activity via button clicks (start, stop)

No exceptions are printed. Also the file is created at the desired location. But with no content (0bytes). All the required manifest and runtime permissions are given. What i'm doing wrong here.

Here is my service

```java
public class MediaCaptureService extends Service {
    public static final String ACTION_ALL = "ALL";
    public static final String ACTION_START = "ACTION_START";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP = "ACTION_STOP";
    public static final String EXTRA_RESULT_CODE = "EXTRA_RESULT_CODE";
    public static final String EXTRA_ACTION_NAME = "ACTION_NAME";

    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    NotificationCompat.Builder _notificationBuilder;
    NotificationManager _notificationManager;
    private String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "ChannelId";
    private String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "Channel";
    private String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESC = "ChannelDescription";
    private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    private static final String ONGING_NOTIFICATION_TICKER = "RecorderApp";

    int BufferElements2Rec = 1024; // want to play 2048 (2K) since 2 bytes we use only 1024
    int BytesPerElement = 2; // 2 bytes in 16bit format

    AudioRecord _recorder;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    private MediaProjectionManager _mediaProjectionManager;
    private MediaProjection _mediaProjection;

    Intent _callingIntent;

    public MediaCaptureService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //Call Start foreground with notification
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MediaCaptureService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            _notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setContentTitle("Starting Service")
                    .setContentText("Starting monitoring service")
                    .setTicker(ONGING_NOTIFICATION_TICKER)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            Notification notification = _notificationBuilder.build();
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESC);
            _notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            _notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            _mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        _callingIntent = intent;

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_ALL);
        registerReceiver(_actionReceiver, filter);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void startRecording(Intent intent) {
        //final int resultCode = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_RESULT_CODE, 0);
        _mediaProjection = _mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(-1, intent);
        startRecording(_mediaProjection);
    }

    @TargetApi(29)
    private void startRecording(MediaProjection mediaProjection ) {
        AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration config =
                new AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder(mediaProjection)
                        .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .build();
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat.Builder()
                .setEncoding(RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING)
                .setSampleRate(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE)
                .setChannelMask(RECORDER_CHANNELS)
                .build();
        _recorder = new AudioRecord.Builder()
 //               .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
                .setBufferSizeInBytes(BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement)
                .setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig(config)
                .build();

        _recorder.startRecording();
        writeAudioDataToFile();
    }

    private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
        int shortArrsize = sData.length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
            bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
            bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
            sData[i] = 0;
        }
        return bytes;

    }

    private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
        // Write the output audio in byte
        Log.i(MainActivity.LOG_PREFIX, "Recording started. Computing output file name");
        File sampleDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "/TestRecordingDasa1");
        if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
            sampleDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String fileName = "Record-" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss").format(new Date()) + ".pcm";
        String filePath = sampleDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
        //String filePath = "/sdcard/voice8K16bitmono.pcm";
        short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];

        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (isRecording) {
            // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format
            _recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
            System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
            try {
                // // writes the data to file from buffer
                // // stores the voice buffer
                byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
                os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i(MainActivity.LOG_PREFIX, String.format("Recording finished. File saved to '%s'", filePath));
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void stopRecording() {
        // stops the recording activity
        if (null != _recorder) {
            isRecording = false;
            _recorder.stop();
            _recorder.release();
            _recorder = null;
        }

        _mediaProjection.stop();

        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(_actionReceiver);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver _actionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_ALL)) {
                String actionName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ACTION_NAME);
                if (actionName != null && !actionName.isEmpty()) {
                    if (actionName.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_START)) {
                        startRecording(_callingIntent);
                    } else if (actionName.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_STOP)){
                        stopRecording();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

And here is an extract from the main activity where the service and start / stop actions are started.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String LOG_PREFIX = "CALL_FUNCTION_TEST";

    private static final int ALL_PERMISSIONS_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int CREATE_SCREEN_CAPTURE = 1001;

    Button _btnInitCapture;
    Button _btnStartCapture;
    Button _btnStopCapture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _btnGetOkPermissions = findViewById(R.id.btnGetOkPermissions);
        _btnGetOkPermissions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkOkPermissions();
            }
        });

        _btnInitCapture = findViewById(R.id.btnInitCapture);
        _btnInitCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                initAudioCapture();
            }
        });

        _btnStartCapture = findViewById(R.id.btnStartCapture);
        _btnStartCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startRecording();
            }
        });

        _btnStopCapture = findViewById(R.id.btnStopAudioCapture);
        _btnStopCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopRecording();
            }
        });
    }

    ...

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void initAudioCapture() {
        _manager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = _manager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_SCREEN_CAPTURE);
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent();
        broadCastIntent.setAction(MediaCaptureService.ACTION_ALL);
        broadCastIntent.putExtra(MediaCaptureService.EXTRA_ACTION_NAME, MediaCaptureService.ACTION_STOP);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent();
        broadCastIntent.setAction(MediaCaptureService.ACTION_ALL);
        broadCastIntent.putExtra(MediaCaptureService.EXTRA_ACTION_NAME, MediaCaptureService.ACTION_START);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (CREATE_SCREEN_CAPTURE == requestCode) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, MediaCaptureService.class);
                i.setAction(MediaCaptureService.ACTION_START);
                i.putExtra(MediaCaptureService.EXTRA_RESULT_CODE, resultCode);
                i.putExtras(intent);
                this.startService(i);
            } else {
                // user did not grant permissions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nothing sets `isRecording` true. Also, you're doing your recording in a blocking method, but you're on the UI thread, which ought to cause your interface to freeze as soon as you start recording.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks alot.

Comment: @asasamar You're welcome. Consider learning the Android Studio debugger, and how to set breakpoints; it's an invaluable skill.